# How to discover through Reflection the base-base-base class from a class?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following scenario:

```
public class BaseEntity { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class BaseAcademicEntity : BaseEntity { ... }
public class BaseFinancialEntity : BaseEntity { ... }

public class Student : BaseAcademicEntity {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Grade CurrentGrade { get; set; }
}
public class Grade : BaseAcademicEntity {
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Ok, now I'll discover the properties from Student class through Reflection.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Student).GetProperties()) {

    // Here I can discover the type of the current property.
    var type = property.PropertyType;

    // now, how to discover if this property is from BaseEntity type?
}
```

Like I wrote in the comment, how to discover if the property is from the BaseEntity type? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
if (typeof(BaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type))
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a System.Type object, you can iteratively look at the 'BaseType' property until it is null or that it's 'BaseEntity'.

Comment: I already did this approach. It's working, but I want a more elegant solution.

Comment: I think Jon's solution is more elegant (wished I'd thought of it).